# Is cordova.file not compatible with iOS10? in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

try this,

> 1. ionic start new_project --v2
> 2. ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file (in your new_project dir)
> 3. `declare let cordova:any;` below import in your home.ts
> 4. then add this in your HomePage class constructor:
>    `console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory); //and make app stuck in white screen forever.`
>
> 5.ionic run ios (in my case iOS simulator runs) ('ionic platform add ios' if not there)

I did nothing special. I have no problem on android. Any work arounds for iOS?